# can't push spring boot application repository from github to heroku

Tags: github, heroku

I created a spring boot application in eclipse with just web dependency, and a single template I called index.html.
I managed to push my application to github, but It failed to push to Heroku,
It gave me this log error
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project hanoiproject12: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
!     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
!     Push failed

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/63814974/9095551

Comment: where can i find this system.properties file

Comment: You need to create it at the root of your project