# spring boot - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

I am trying to publish my spring boot (with posgres) database on Heroku but i keep receiving this error:

***Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project Art-Gallery: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 18 -> [Help 1]***

Below is my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>frontend</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Heroku uses Java 8 by default but you can override that, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63814974/9095551

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<properties>
 <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

adding this code to my pom file actually worked and fixed my error

[Maven build Compilation error : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525139/maven-build-compilation-error-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-plugins)

Answer (score 0):

For more explanation:
Your spring boot project is built on JDK version more than the image Heroku uses to containerize your app so the problem is solved when you change JDK version.